# Efficient repeated numpy.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause, computational-geometry

I have a code in which I want to check whether pairs of coordinates fall into certain rectangles. However, there are many rectangles and i am not sure how to generalize the following code to many rectangles. I only can do it using `eval` in a loop but that is quite ugly.

Here is a code which checks to which of the rectangles each entry of a `DataFrame` consisting of coordinates. It assigns 0 if it belongs to the first, 1 for the second, an `nan` otherwise. I want to have such a code that would produce the analogous result assuming we have a large list of Rectangle objects, without applying `eval` or loops in the last row. Thanks alot.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

rec1 = Rectangle((0,0), 100, 100)
rec2 = Rectangle((100,0), 100, 100)
x = np.random.poisson(100, size=200)
y = np.random.poisson(80, size=200)
xy = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x, "y" : y}).values
e1 = np.asarray(rec1.get_extents())
e2 = np.asarray(rec2.get_extents())
r1m1, r1m2 = np.min(e1), np.max(e1)
r2m1, r2m2 = np.min(e2), np.max(e2)
out = np.where(((xy >= r1m1) & (xy <= r1m2)).all(axis=1), 0, 
               np.where(((xy >= r2m1) & (xy <= r2m2)).all(axis=1), 1, np.nan))
```

**EDIT** Here is a version with 3 rectangles

```
rec1 = Rectangle((0,0), 100, 100)
rec2 = Rectangle((0,100), 100, 100)
rec3 = Rectangle((100,100), 100, 100)
x = np.random.poisson(100, size=200)
y = np.random.poisson(100, size=200)
xy = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x, "y" : y}).values
e1 = np.asarray(rec1.get_extents())
e2 = np.asarray(rec2.get_extents())
e3 = np.asarray(rec3.get_extents())
r1m1, r1m2 = np.min(e1), np.max(e1)
r2m1, r2m2 = np.min(e2), np.max(e2)
r3m1, r3m2 = np.min(e3), np.max(e3)
out = np.where(((xy >= r1m1) & (xy <= r1m2)).all(axis=1), 0, 
           np.where(((xy >= r2m1) & (xy <= r2m2)).all(axis=1), 1, 
           np.where(((xy >= r3m1) & (xy <= r3m2)).all(axis=1), 2, np.nan)))
```

What I like to get are values of 0, 1, 2 or np.nan. But the output is consists only of 0 and 1.

Comment: Are you using loops? I am not seeing any.

Comment: Thanks @Divakar, I am not using loops. But I do not know how to have an analogous row to the last one, that would go through many rectangles (not only 2), without a loop.

Comment: So, the output `out` for each pt in `xy` would be `1` if and only if the pt is within bounds of ALL given rectangles? Also, can we assume all the extents of the rectangles being store in a multi-dim array, like a 3D array?

Comment: In the case of 2 rectangles yes. But I would like to generalize this code, to obtain efficient classification of the rectangle to which each pair of coordinates belongs, given a list of Rectangles objects.

Comment: I am not clear on the "pair" part. Could you add another rectangle object and show us the expected output?

Comment: I added an edit, showing my failed attempt at approaching it. By pair I mean pair of (x,y) coordinates, which are the rows of the above `xy`.

Comment: A non-pandas way of getting `xy` is `xy=np.stack((x,y),axis=-1)`

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, I will use that. I am still looking for the answer on how to classify belonging to each rectangle in a set of rectangles.

Comment: Your nested `where` expression is unreadable.  And for those of us who haven't used `Rectangle` the derivation of the `r?m?` values is unnecessarily obscure.

Comment: Trying to understand the logic of getting `0,1,2` or `nan`. So, we would get `0` if the coresponding pt is within the bounds of `rec1`, `1` if within bounds of `rec2`, `2` if within bounds of `rec3` and `nan` otherwise? If so, what if the pt is within bounds of two ore more rectangles?

Comment: @Divakar: thankfully, my rectangles are mutually exclusive, so that will not occur.

Comment: Again, not clear on the `0,1,2 or nan` as outputs. Could you clarify when do we get each of those? Did I assume it correctly in my previous comment?

Comment: the output should be an array called `out` whose length is `xy.shape[0]`. Each entry of the array `out` should be a number, corresponding to the index of the rectangles. So each for each row in `xy` is mapped, the corresponding entry in `out` is the rectangle to which the coordinates in this row of `xy` belong to.

Comment: So the structure is `where(cond1, 0, where(cond2, 1, where(cond3, 2, ..)))` - multinesting of the 3 parameter version of `where`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach making use of [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
# Store extents in a 3D array
e = np.dstack((e1,e2,e3))

# Get a valid mask for the X's and Y's and then the combined one
x_valid_mask = (xy[:,0] >= e[0,0,:,None]) & (xy[:,0] <= e[1,0,:,None])
y_valid_mask = (xy[:,1] >= e[0,1,:,None]) & (xy[:,1] <= e[1,1,:,None])
valid_mask = x_valid_mask & y_valid_mask

# Finally use argmax() to choose the rectangle each pt belongs. We can use
# argmax to choose the first matching one and that works here because
# we are guaranteed to have the recatnagles mutually exclusive
out = np.where(valid_mask.any(0), valid_mask.argmax(0), np.nan)
```

Let's have a sample run to verify things here -

1) Setup random inputs :

```
In [315]: rec1 = Rectangle((0,0), 100, 100)
     ...: rec2 = Rectangle((0,100), 100, 100)
     ...: rec3 = Rectangle((100,100), 100, 100)
     ...: 

In [316]: e1 = np.asarray(rec1.get_extents())
     ...: e2 = np.asarray(rec2.get_extents())
     ...: e3 = np.asarray(rec3.get_extents())
     ...:
```

2) Taking at look at extents for `rec3` :

```
In [317]: e3
Out[317]: 
array([[ 100.,  100.],
       [ 200.,  200.]])
```

3) Get random 5 pts for `xy` :

```
In [319]: x = np.random.poisson(100, size=5)
     ...: y = np.random.poisson(100, size=5)
     ...: xy = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x, "y" : y}).values
     ...:
```

4) Let's setup the `pt[1]` such that its inside `rec3`. So, the o/p for this pt should be `2`.

```
In [320]: xy[1] = [150,175]
```

5) Let's setup `pt[3]` such that its outside all of the rectangles. So, the correponding o/p should be a `NaN`.

```
In [321]: xy[3] = [400,400]
```

6) Run posted codes and print output :

```
In [323]: out
Out[323]: array([ nan,   2.,   2.,  nan,   2.])
```

As seen `out[1]` is `2` and `out[3]` is `NaN`, which were anticipated earlier.

Answer (score 2):

matplotlib has a built-in routine `contains_point` for checking if a point is contained in a polygon object which is quite fast.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

rec1 = Rectangle((0, 0), 100, 100)
rec1.contains_point((1, 1))
# True
rec1.contains_point((101, 101))
# False
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested wheres like this are hard to read and extend:

```
where(cond1, 0, where(cond2, 1, where(cond3, 2, ..)))
```

You'll see from other questions that `where` is used most often to generate indices, that is the `I,J=np.where(cond)` version instead of the `np.where(cond, 0, x)` version.

So I'd be tempted, just for clarity, to write your code as

```
res = xy.copy()   # or np.zeros_like(xy)
for i in range(n):
    ij = np.where(cond[i]
    res[ij] = i
```